# For which $a$ does the system of linear equations have a root

Tags: linear-algebra

Choose a possible $a$ such that the linear equations have a root

$$\begin{matrix} x+2y+3z=a \\
                 4x+5y+6z=a^2 \\
                 7x+8y+9z=a^3 \end{matrix}$$

Do I begin by finding the possible values of $a$ such that the system is consistent?

Comment: what is determinant of coefficient matrix???

Comment: The determinant of the coefficient matrix is equal to $0$. Thus the only solution to $Ax=0$ is the trivial solution. I am not sure where to go from there as we are not trying to solve $Ax=0$.

Comment: do you mean if $A$ has determinant $0$, then $Ax=0$ has only zero solution???

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If you do Row Reduced Echelon Form (RREF), Gaussian Elimination, you can reduce the system to a form where you can see the possible values that make it consistent.

There is more than one answer, but that is okay because the problem said to choose a possible $a$.

**Spoiler** (Hover over the following area.)

> $~~~~~~~~~~~~a = 0$ and $a = 1$ are two such examples.

You might also be able to look at the determinant, but that is not always fruitful.

Comment: I found that any vector that lies in the span of $(1,4,7)$ and $(2,5,8)$ will make the system consistent. I can see that $a=1$ and $a=0$ clearly satisfy this. I guess my question is how does a system being consistent imply that there exists a root?

Comment: Definition Consistent System: A system of linear equations is consistent if it has at least one solution. Otherwise, the system is called inconsistent. For $a = 0$ or $a=1$, we can find an infinite number of solutions. See http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-b-matrices-and-systems-of-equations/session-14-solutions-to-square-systems/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_m3.pdf

Comment: @user98577: When we have a consistent system with no free variables, we have a unique solution. When we have a consistent with free variables, we have an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Just to clarify for my understanding, if we choose $a=1$ does the system $Ax=1$ necessarily have a root? The question asks for me to choose a possible $a$ such that a root exist, $a=0$ obviously works since we then have $Ax=0$.

Comment: Yes it does, that is correct. With $a = 1$, we get: $y = 1 - 2z$, $x = -1 + z$, $z$ is free. Try some values to prove it works. For example: $z =0, y = 1, x = -1$. Regards

Comment: Yes it is thank you, I was previously unaware of the relationship between consistency implying the existence of roots. Is this always case? In other words, if I can find a system is consistent for some $b$ can I immediately conclude the system has roots for that $b$.

Comment: I did upvote the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Nice answer, and great follow-up... +1

Answer (score 0):

Then first equation plus the third equation minus twice the second yields $a^3-2a^2+a=a(a-1)^2=0$.

Comment: Also 1 would be fine, because (a-1) for $a=1$ is also 0.